# Is onaah prohibited for mitzvah items

Tags: halacha, mitzvah, choshen-mishpat-civil-law, transactions, business

According to Halacha, Jews should  not overcharge significantly when selling items (Onaah) on the principle it’s bad to price higher than a product’s value. However, there are statements throughout Tanakh (say Tehillim 19:11) about  Torah being more precious than honey and gold. Therefor, is it permissible to sell mitzvah items (teffilin, Tallit, lulav, Shabbat candles etc.)  beyond their market rate?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Sukkah.34b.6?lang=bi&with=all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Shulchan Aruch, Choshen Mishpat 227:15](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Choshen_Mishpat.227.15?lang=he&with=Commentary%20ConnectionsList&lang2=he), ultimately from Bava Metzia 58b:

> בכל מטלטלים שייך אונאה אפילו בספרים
>
> Onaah applies to all movable objects, even [holy] books

In Bava Metzia there R. Yehudah states that onaah does not apply to "a Sefer Torah," and the Sages disagree, with the halachah following them. Pischei Teshuvah on Shulchan Aruch there cites Teshuvos Chasam Sofer, Choshen Mishpat 123 (should be [143](https://www.sefaria.org/Responsa_Chatam_Sofer%2C_Choshen_Mishpat.143?vhe=Pressburg,_1855-1864&lang=he)), that the Poskim changed the wording from "Sefer Torah" to "sefarim" because in the era of the Mishnah people learned directly from Sifrei Torah, while now they learn from books.

At any rate, we see from this that onaah indeed applies to mitzvah items.

Comment: It's important to note that some poskim hold that there is no Issur of Ona'ah in contemporary markets and others hold admit there at least isn't any by Etrogim.